# Why nomicon layout chapter &Vec<&'static str> couldn't be used where an &Vec<&'a str> was expected?

Tags: rust

https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/vec-layout.html

I don't understand when Vec defined as

```
pub struct Vec<T> {
    ptr: *mut T,
    cap: usize,
    len: usize,
}
```

And quoting:

> And indeed this would compile. Unfortunately, it would be incorrect. First, the compiler will give us too strict variance. So a `&Vec<&'static str>` couldn't be used where an `&Vec<&'a str>` was expected. More importantly, it will give incorrect ownership information to the drop checker, as it will conservatively assume we don't own any values of type T.

I have tried the code below ([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=94de99bdc5b8dc9c3439ee081b43ae23)) but it works.

```
pub struct TestVec<T> {
    raw: *mut T,
    len: usize,
    cap: usize,
}

impl<T> TestVec<T> {
    pub fn new()->Self {
        TestVec { raw: std::mem::MaybeUninit::uninit().as_mut_ptr(), len:0, cap:0}
    }
}

fn test1(a: &TestVec<&str>) {
}

fn test() {
    let v:TestVec<&'static str> = TestVec::new();
    test1(&v);
}

fn main() {
    test();
}
```

Where am I wrong? Or is there any example code?

Comment: work and compile are two different thing that you confuse.

Answer (score 3):

This statement is about type variance, which is a tricky concept about relations between types, actually a special kind of subtyping.

Your example does not contain variance. It is desugared to:

```
fn test1<'x, 'y>(a: &'x TestVec<&'y str>)
```

And when you call this function using `v: TestVec<&'static str>`, the lifetime `'x` is resolved to that of `v` and `'y` is `'static`. There is no type variance here, just generics.

But consider this other example that does require variance:

```
fn test2<'x>(a: &TestVec<&'x str>, b: &TestVec<&'x str>) {}

fn test_variance<'a>() {
    let v1:TestVec<&'static str> = TestVec::new();
    let v2:TestVec<&'a str> = TestVec::new();
    test2(&v1, &v2);
}
```

Now the compiler should solve `'x` as the shortest lifetime of `'a` and `'static`, that should be just `'a`, because of variance. But the `*mut T` in `TestVec` causes this error:

```
cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter 'a in function call due to conflicting requirement
...
   = note: expected `&TestVec<&str>`
              found `&TestVec<&'static str>`
```

Then, as the Nomicon explains, changing the `*mut T` to `*const T` makes it work again.

Comment: Thanks! I have another questions: what the difference when we add PhantomData<T>? What will drop check do when there is a PhantomData<T> field?

Comment: AFAIUI, the `*{mut,const} T` does not affect the dropck in any way. Thus, the `PhantomData<T>` makes dropck behave as if it were a plain `T`. Without it, it could be unsound to access the `*const T` in the `TestVec::Drop` implementation, something like [this example](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1238-nonparametric-dropck.md#examples-of-code-that-will-start-to-be-rejected).